How can I use "den Reiz ausmachen" correctly?
I was a bit confused by the actual meaning of "den Reiz ausmachen", and do we consider this as a Nomen-Verb Verbindung? What are the synonyms and everyday uses of it?
Here is the sentence with the verb I came across: "Forscher glauben, dass der Gegensatz zu unserer Zeit heute den Reiz ausmacht. Die Rollen der Menschen damals waren klar definiert …"

No, it's just one of the less obvious meanings of the verb ausmachen.

etwas(Akk) ausmachen — to amount to something, to constitute something


Die Planung macht den Großteil der Arbeit aus.


Forscher glauben, dass der Gegensatz zu unserer Zeit heute den Reiz ausmacht.
Forscher glauben, dass der Reiz im Gegensatz zu unserer Zeit heute besteht.

